# How to use LISTAGG to return rows prefixed with quotes

Tags: oracle

I am trying to return rows which would be useful for setting the in condition in a query.
Here is my query

```
SELECT LISTAGG(PRODUCTID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RowSequence) FROM DWRE_ITEM_V
```

which return Order1,Order2

I would like it to return 'Order1','Order2'

I tried using the concat operator || with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT LISTAGG(''''||PRODUCTID||'''', ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RowSequence) 
FROM DWRE_ITEM_V
```

Comment: I tried with just \' and it didn't work why do we need to give four 4 ' to make it work

Comment: giving a ' before another ' is used to escape single quotes inside a string in a sql statement.so in total it becomes four quotes to append a single quote as prefix.

Comment: @Raj -this is obviously the correct answer, so after you test it on your data please mark it so.