# Unable to use LISTAGG output in a subquery. ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I am getting the comma separated value from the below query
    `SELECT LISTAGG('''' || student_name || '''',',') 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY student_name)
FROM students;`

However, when I put in subquery it doesn't give any result.
`select  * from students where student_name in ('A', 'B');` --give two rows

`select  * from students where student_name in (SELECT LISTAGG('''' || student_name || '''',',') 
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY student_name)
FROM students;)` -- no rows

Comment: This is follow up for `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854040/how-to-use-listagg-to-return-rows-prefixed-with-quotes`

Comment: For those who prefer to to be able to click on a hypertext link this is a follow-up to [this old StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39854040/146325)

Answer (score 2):

You don't understand how `in` works.  It does not work with strings.  It works with multiple items.

So, the right way to write the logic is:

```
select  *
from students
where student_name in (select student_name from students) -- no rows;
```

Your query is essentially doing:

```
where student_name in ('aaron,beth,calvin,debbie,...')
```

The `in` list has one item, so this is equivalent to:

```
where student_name = 'aaron,beth,calvin,debbie,...'
```

And no student name (if you have more than one row) can be the concatenated names of all the students.

Comment: My string has multiple comma separated items in `single quotes` as 
`'A','B','C','D','E'`. I can see it when I run the first query (with LISTAGG) sepearately.

Comment: @krishnakant . . . No.  It is one string with lots of commas in the string.